# Search based on lookup field relationship

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, lookup-column

Given the following lists and their lookup relationship. How can I search for "Sassy" and return the owner "David Wavid"? Searching for "Chihuahua" works fine, but the search doesn't seem to look at any of the other columns in the related dog list.

I can get this working using "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" and adding "Personality", but I'd rather the search just respected the relationship.

Owner List

```
Firstname | Surname | Dog (lookup column to dog list showing "Breed")  
Bob         Bobbins   Labrador
David       Wavid     Chihuahua
```

Dog List

```
Breed     | Breed Group | Personality
Labrador    Gundog        Friendly
Chihuahua   Toy           Sassy
```

Using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise for a Publishing site.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise for a Publishing site. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint treats all "items" as single entities. The only place where you can specify a different behavior for Parent-Child relationships is via the BCS. So you have two options.

1. Write a bit of JavaScript in a Display Template that, when the "Sassy" result is returned it fetches (pun intended) the linked items from the other list. This is pretty trivial stuff if you use the Search REST API.
2. Write a BCS External Content Type that joins your two lists and specify the necessary parameters for including children in the crawl. (NOTE: I haven't tried this since 2010 so your mileage may vary.)

Comment: I was hoping SharePoint had a better standard offering. I wonder if there are any performance implications for option 1, possibly fine with a single "join", but some of our data has multiple lookup fields.

Comment: It all depends on how you write it.